# mount error : cifs filesystem not supported by the system

Tags: arch-linux, cifs

Sometime ago I used to mount shared folders from my windows computer using the command :

```
sudo mount.cifs //computer/folder /mnt -o username=user
```

However now it bugs and yields :

> mount error : cifs filesystem not supported by the system mount
>
> error(19): No such device

Any idea on what might have happened in the meanwhile that prevents it from working ?

The package cifs-utils is installed..

```
zgrep -i cifs /proc/config.gz
```

Returns :

```
CONFIG_CIFS=m
CONFIG_CIFS_STATS=y
#CONFIG_CIFS_STATS2 is not set
CONFIG_CIFS_WEAK_PW_HASH=y
...
```

All yes except for STATS2 and DEBUG basically

Comment: `zgrep -i cifs /proc/config.gz` ? (That shall print if CIFS it is compiled as a module)

Comment: @grochmal added output in edit

Comment: Good, CIFS is compiled as a module.  Load the CIFS module with `modprobe cifs` and you should be able to perform the mount (i'm ~90% confident).

Comment: @grochmal it worked again after a reboot, if it happens again i'll do that, thanks

Answer (score 13):

CONFIG_CIFS=m means the CIFS functionality is compiled into a kernel module.
If the cifs module isn't loaded after a reboot, you can append a line

```
cifs
```

to the file /etc/modules. The file lists modules which will be loaded automatically at boot time. To check if the module is already loaded type:

```
lsmod | grep cifs
```

If you don't see 'cifs' in the output, it isn't loaded. To load it manually without a reboot:

```
modprobe cifs
```

Comment: Also, if you've updated your kernel, the module changes. So `modprobe cifs` may fail and you have to reboot anyway as your running kernel version is not the same as the current module directory version.

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar problem, the module location was changed because of rolling release arch distribution, so path was different. Reboot

Answer (score 1):

Here is yet another tip for mounting a Windows share:

```
sudo mount -t drvfs '\\your computer IP address or computername here\share'  /mnt
```

The key is to use the single quotes for the source drive.

Answer (score 0):

your Ubuntu can not find cifs in filesystem. it is not necessary to add cifs.ko to kernel. you can treat it in menuconfig in kernel and choose cifs in filesystem. after that copy the new zImage.

finally

```
sudo mount -t cifs //computer ip/sharedfolder /mnt
```